# fetch data is providing some [assets] and [objects]. How can I de-structure these in the following code in order to list them out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the data I'm receiving:

```json
{
      market_contract: 'atomicmarket',
      assets_contract: 'atomicassets',
      sale_id: '278354',
      seller: 'stexpr',
      buyer: null,
      offer_id: '280670',
      price: [Object],
      listing_price: '5000000',
      listing_symbol: 'XUSDC',
      assets: [Array],
      maker_marketplace: 'protonmint',
      taker_marketplace: null,
      collection_name: '355532155243',
      collection: [Object],
      is_seller_contract: false,
      updated_at_block: '116895433',
      updated_at_time: '1646077501500',
      created_at_block: '116895433',
      created_at_time: '1646077501500',
      ordinality: '58',
      state: 1
}
```

This is the code I'm using to list some of the items out:

```
  const res = await fetch(
    'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales'
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

function UserTransactions({ data }) {
  const results = data;
  console.log(results);
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div>This is a list of User Transactions!</div>
      <ul>
        {results.data.map((result) => {
          const { sale_id, buyer, seller, assets } = result;

          return (
            <li key={data.id}>
              <h3>
                {seller} just sold {sale_id} to {buyer} for{' '}
              </h3>
              <img src={assets} alt={sale_id} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default UserTransactions;
```

I'm able to create list items of sale_id,buyer, and seller just fine. Assets, on the other hand, does not work. What can I do to make it list out?

Comment: (1) What does "does not work" mean? Please be specific. (2) You are using `assets` as a string, but it is an array. As far as we can tell, it may have 0 items, 1 item, or 100 items. You will need to decide and describe what behavior you want for those possibilities. That has not been described in the question. Probably, you want to use `assets.map` to yield some markup for each asset, but that is just a guess based on the names of things. (3) `key={data.id}` should not be used inside your map function because it will cause duplicate keys. There's one `data` and many `result`.

Comment: (1) I mean it does not list out like the rest do.
(2) How (or where) can I map it out like  I mapped out the original data? You mention **assets.map** but were can I put that in this code? 
(3) what do you recommend for the **key** then?

Comment: What do you mean by "list out"? Based on the names and the example data, 1 result has 1 sale_id, 1 buyer, 1 seller, and many assets. How would you "list out" this collection of assets? For example, as a comma-separated list all under the same <h3>? Or do you actually want one <h3> entry per asset? Or do you actually expect only 1 asset, no matter what? The intent is not clear here so I could not say where/how to use the `map` function. I recommend to add details about the goal to the question. An example of the desired output would answer most questions people would have.

Comment: by **list out** I mean that with the exception of  **assets** , I was able to create list items and have them show up on the app I am building. When I try to create a **list item** for **assets**, it gives me this error and error saying **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys..... If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** So I'm trying to see how to grab the information that's inside of that **assets** and then map it, then create a list item of what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions from unclear parts of the question:

- `assets` is an array of strings, where each string is an image URL.
- You wanted 1 `<li>` per asset per result, not 1 `<li>` per result.

Then it will not be enough to have one [`.map(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You need an inner `map` over each result's `assets` array. Then the outer map can change to be a [`.flatMap(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) so that it "flattens" the inner `map`'s individual arrays into a single array of `<li>` items.

```js
{results.data.flatMap((result) => {
    const { sale_id, buyer, seller, assets } = result;

    return assets.map((asset) => (
        <li key={sale_id + '|' + asset}>
            <h3>
                {seller} just sold {sale_id} to {buyer} for{' '}
            </h3>
            <img src={asset} alt={sale_id} />
        </li>
    ));
})}
```

Note have I have also changed the list element `key=` so that [it uniquely refers to the identity of the listed data](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).